# How to modify this JS code to search for exact, whole word/number

Tags: javascript, search

I'm currently working on a search engine (masonry + isotope + custom code provided below). I would like it to display only exact matches of only whole words or numbers entered by a user, apart from searching by classes of divs etc (this and everything else works fine).

Current situation:
When user inputs "1", paragraphs containing e.g. "12" are displayed too

Desired result:
When user inputs "1", only results containing "1" are displayed - NOT paragraphs containing numbers like 221, 111, 12 etc.

I would be very grateful for providing working code.

```
var qsRegex;
var buttonFilter;


var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  filter: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
    var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
    return searchResult && buttonResult;
  }
});

$('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
  buttonFilter = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
  $grid.isotope();
});


var $quicksearch = $('#quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
  qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
  $grid.isotope();
}) );



$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
  var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
  $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});



function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
  var timeout;
  return function debounced() {
    if ( timeout ) {
      clearTimeout( timeout );
    }
    function delayed() {
      fn();
      timeout = null;
    }
    setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to tweek your regex so that the input is surrounded by a space... this is a decent website to try regex out on, though it is ruby focused, it has a regex cheat sheet http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out myself:

```
 qsRegex = new RegExp( "\\b" + $quicksearch.val() + "\\b", 'gi' );
```